# Как отобразить приложение Android Tv в разделе Play Movies & TV

Tags: java, android, android-tv

Есть приложение Android Tv. В приложении можно смотреть телевиденье и фильмы, приложение есть в гугл плей. Как сделать так чтобы приложение отображалось в разделе Play Movies & TV? Беда в том что у меня даже нету телевизора с android tv приходиться проверять все на эмуляторах. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разве это вообще для приложений раздел? там фильмы же.

Comment: А кстати да, надо про это сказать. Спасибо. Хотя тв тоже присутствует а это явно программа.

Comment: возможно под тв имеются ввиду тв сериалы и подобное.